# Delete properties from object that are not in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I'm using adonisjs, and am trying to sanitize a post request on the server. The data I get back has extra properties that are not mapped to the table/model so it is erroring when I try to save. Here is the update method

```
async update ({ params, request, response }) {
  const contract = await Contract.find(params.id);
  contract.merge(request.post());
  return await contract.save();
}
```

The problem is that when I returned the contract earlier on a get request, I added some computed properties. I could do something along the lines of

```
const { prop1, prop2 } = request.post();
```

but that doesn't feel like a future proof or clean solution. Ideally I want the object to only have the properties defined on the table/model. I have a validator setup as described in [the validator docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/validator), but it still lets other properties bypass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a beforeSave hook in the model class that filter's properties on the object, which allows us to keep a thin controller.

```
const FIELDS = ['id', 'description'];

class Contract extends Model {
  static boot() {
    super.boot();
    this.addHook('beforeSave', async contractInstance => {
      Object.keys(contractInstance.$attributes).forEach(key => {
        if (!CONTRACT_FIELDS.includes(key)) {
          delete contractInstance.$attribute[key];
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about an helper class?

```
class RequestContractExtractor{
  static desiredProps = [
    "prop1",
    "prop2",
  ]; // you could replace this with a list you get from your model class

  constructor(requestData){
    desiredProps.forEach(prop => this[prop] = requestData[prop]);
  }

  static from(...args){ return new this(...args); }
}
```

Then you'd be able to do:

```
async update ({ params, request, response }) {
  const contract = await Contract.find(params.id);
  contract.merge(RequestContractExtractor.from(request.post()));
  return await contract.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a beforeSave hook that filter's properties on the object.

Create a file at `/app/Model/Hooks/ContractHook.js`

```
'use strict'

const ContractHook = module.exports = {}

const CONTRACT_FIELDS = ["id", "description"];
ContractHook.removeDynamicFields = async (contractInstance) => {
  if (contractInstance) {
    Object.keys(contractInstance.$attributes).forEach((key) => {
      if (!CONTRACT_FIELDS.includes(key) && contractInstance.$attributes[key]) {
        delete contractInstance.$attributes[key];
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Use it in your model like so...

```
class Contract extends Model {
  static boot() {
    super.boot();

    this.addHook("beforeCreate", [
      "ContractHook.removeDynamicFields",
    ]);
  }
```